# Running a SlimerJS + headless Firefox script through PHP on webserver?

Tags: php, firefox, slimerjs

On my server (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS), I have a Firefox installed, as well as `xvfb` for headless Firefox operation, and CasperJS with SlimerJS. I also have a CasperJS script which works fine. I want to utilize this script from PHP; this is the essence of my PHP script for this, let's call it `mytest.php`:

```php
echo "php_sapi_name() " . php_sapi_name() . "\n"; // "cli" for php cli, "apache2handler" for php via webserver

chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

$nodeModPath = "/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules";

putenv("SLIMERJSLAUNCHER=/usr/bin/firefox46");
$cmdline = "xvfb-run $nodeModPath/casperjs/bin/casperjs --engine=slimerjs --debug=true mySlimerScript.js";

$returnString = shell_exec($cmdline);
echo "$returnString\n";
```

---

EDIT: Note that the command could as well be just:

```
$cmdline = "xvfb-run $nodeModPath/casperjs/bin/casperjs --engine=slimerjs --debug=true 2>&1";
```

... that is, without any JS script listed - in which case the help should be dumped (and is, in case of CLI access - but the same error as below is reported when accessing through webserver)

---

When I run this PHP script from the terminal command line (via SSH), that is through PHP in CLI mode:

```
$ php mytest.php
```

... everything runs fine, there is no problem whatsoever.

However, when I invoke this PHP script online through the webserver, that is via `http://example.com/mytest.php`, it fails first with the error:

```
Gecko error: it seems /usr/bin/firefox46 is not compatible with SlimerJS.
See Gecko version compatibility. If version is correct, launch slimerjs
with --debug=true to see Firefox error message
```

... and after adding `--debug=true` (as already included in the example above), I additionally get this error:

```
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm, line 63: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]
```

So, apparently my headless Firefox does not want to run, when PHP is invoked through the webserver (in which case, PHP reports that it uses the `apache2handler` SAPI).

Would anyone know why this happens - and how can I get the script to execute properly when called from a webserver, just as when it runs under PHP CLI mode?

---

EDIT 2: Can now reconstruct this error via CLI mode too, and can confirm it is due to the user; so without any JS script provided in the `$command`, I get this:

```
$ sudo -H -u root php mytest.php
...
Usage: casperjs [options] script.[js|coffee] [script argument [script argument ...]]
       casperjs [options] test [test path [test path ...]]
       casperjs [options] selftest
...

$ sudo -H -u www-data php mytest.php
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm, line 63: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]
Gecko error: it seems /usr/bin/firefox46 is not compatible with SlimerJS.
See Gecko version compatibility. If version is correct, launch slimerjs
with --debug=true to see Firefox error message
```

Comment: First thoughts : files permissions as running the script in `cli` mode will have the user running it, however, through the webserver, the user will be `www-data`. Possible, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, @php-dev, but I cannot really figure out whose permissions would be the problem; here I call `xvfb-run` which calls `casperjs` which calls `slimerjs` which calls headless Firefox. Is there a way to check for permission errors somewhere in this kind of case? I tried `/var/log/apache2/error-mysite.log`, but it only reports PHP stuff like `Trying to get property of non-object` once the `shell_exec` call fails.

Comment: Try redirecting `stderr` output to `stdout` or a file.

Comment: Thanks @php-dev - I added `2>&1` to the end of the `$cmdline`, but unfortunately I get no new information whatsoever. However, I also tried a direct `shell_exec("xvfb-run /usr/bin/firefox46 2>&1")`, and this one does NOT seem to crash (however, it doesn't exit on its own either, as expected). So seemingly, `xvfb-run` and `firefox` alone are not the problem?!

Answer (score 5):

Well, this was a nasty problem. I ended up doing an `strace`, and comparing the logs, for the `root` user and the `www-data` user when running a full `slimerjs` (the full command line can be found by adding `echo`es to `/path/to/slimerjs-0.10.1-pre/slimerjs`):

```
sudo -H -u www-data strace \
  /usr/bin/firefox46 -app /path/to/slimerjs-0.10.1-pre/application.ini \
  --profile /path/to/firefox-46.0.1/profile-46 -no-remote --debug=true /home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js --casper-path=/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/casperjs \
  --cli 2>&1 \
  | tee /tmp/strace.log

sudo -H -u root strace \
  /usr/bin/firefox46 -app /path/to/slimerjs-0.10.1-pre/application.ini \
  --profile /path/to/firefox-46.0.1/profile-46 -no-remote --debug=true /home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js --casper-path=/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/casperjs \
  --cli 2>&1 \
  | tee /tmp/straceR.log
```

If these logs are now compared in say `meld`, then the eventually start diverging at a point like this:

```
mkdir("/root/.innophi", 0700)           = 0
mkdir("/root/.innophi/slimerjs", 0700)  = 0

... [vs.] ...

mkdir("/var/www/.innophi", 0700)        = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
access("/var/www/.innophi", F_OK)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

So, `casperJS` basically tries to create a directory in the home directory of the user; the problem is , `www-data`'s `$HOME` is `/var/www`, where it seemingly has no write access!

So, the easiest thing for me was to "hack" the `$HOME` environment variable in the `mytest.php` script, and set it to `/tmp`, where `www-data` definitely has write permissions:

```
...
putenv("SLIMERJSLAUNCHER=/usr/bin/firefox46");
putenv("HOME=/tmp");
...
```

... and whaddayaknow, finally the script works under the `www-data` user from CLI too:

```
$ sudo -H -u www-data php test_commands.php
...
Options:

--verbose   Prints log messages to the console
--log-level Sets logging level
--help      Prints this help
...
```

Btw, this `.innophi` directory seems to also be mentioned in https://docs.slimerjs.org/current/configuration.html#profiles ,